# Audi A3 2005 Damaged ignition barrel?

Tags: audi, ignition-key, ignition-switch, immobilizer, a3

I am experiencing a problem with starting my 2005 Audi A3. This morning I inserted the key into the ignition and could not switch it to the ON position. I could only switch it to the Accessory position. I have checked that the wheels are not locked. I tried to wiggle the key as well as wiggle the key while slightly turning the steering wheel. I suspect the ignition key barrel. If I need to disable the steering column cover I would also change the ignition switch as they come as a kit. I would like to make sure that I will not experience any problems with the immobiliser if I change the ignition switch. As far as I understand immobiliser reader is a separate device housed nearby and I could be connected to a new ignition assembly. Lastly, a new key will most likely not have an immobiliser chip or remote control and it will not be programmed. Therefore, I am planning on switching the key in my current fob. At the same time, I would also change the driver's side lock to keep the key universal rather than carrying two keys. This approach assumes that the immobiliser chip is integrated into the fob and that I can connect the immobiliser chip reader to the new assembly. Would like to verify if my assumption is correct. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put some kind of lubricant into the barrel to see if it would turn?

Comment: Hi. Not yet as all I have is WD40. People recommend graphite paste. However, graphite is conductive. Unsure if it is conductive in paste form. Will need to research it. To add a few details the issue is only when switching from ACC to ON once in the ON position it works normally.

Comment: While on the subject I was planning to use compressed air before WD40. My thinking is that it could blow out all loose debris. And then I would use WD40 to lubricate and push all gunk to the bottom of the barrel.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question. The ignition assembly is made of four parts: housing, ignition switch, ignition barrel and immobiliser coil. If the immobiliser coil is removed and fitted to the new assembly the car will start as long as the new key blade (that came with the new ignition barrel) is fitted to the old fob (the fob is where the immobiliser chip is located). This approach requires a swap of the driver’s door lock if we want to keep the key universal for everything in the car. I will add pictures and links to good step-by-step tutorials.